# Play - Java vs. Scala Templates

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm new to Play, and I realize there are two kind of templates:

1) Java-based with the symbols such as ${…}, #{tagName /}, @{…}...

2) Scala-based using only '@' as a special symbol.

I'm not sure are they supposed to exclude each other or to complement and work together.

What are the pros and cons using each one? Chose one template rule or use both?

Comment: Please note that the template engine has changed between Play 1 and Play 2 (just like almost everything else). While I believe that there is a project to bring the old templates to Play 2, your choice of version basically determines which one you're using.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [latest documentation here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplates), play templates only use `@`-syntax at this moment.

If you're interested, the templating engine is now a [separate project](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) from the main playframework, I suppose to better support different engines.